# Add Control to validate in ModelState manually

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I have one scenario as mentioned below :

In my xyz.cshtml page, i have two form. and in xyz.cshtml.cs page i have one InputModel that contains Property for both form.

```
public class InputModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Email field is required.")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Enter a valid email address.")]
        [RegularExpression(
            @"^[A-Za-z0-9](([_\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@([A-Za-z0-9]+)(([\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.([A-Za-z]{2,})$",
            ErrorMessage = "Enter a valid email address.")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Password field is required.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password_ChangeEmail { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The OldPassword field is required.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string OldPassword { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The New Password field is required.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [CustomPassword(8, 15, ErrorMessage = "The password is invalid.")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Confirm Password field is required.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The passwords do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

I am using first 2 property in one form and rest of the property in 2nd form.

Now, issue is when i am pressing Submit button from 1st form, it's validating 2nd form as well. So for the time i have used **ModelState.Clear()** . But if i am using this and i am not wrong it will stop validating all the property.

So, if you guys have any solution like, is it possible to control in ModelState manually for validate.

If i need to share anything else, please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You could split the model into two, one model for each form and use them in the post actions for these forms.

```
public class LoginModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Email field is required.")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Enter a valid email address.")]
    [RegularExpression(
        @"^[A-Za-z0-9](([_\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@([A-Za-z0-9]+)(([\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.([A-Za-z]{2,})$",
        ErrorMessage = "Enter a valid email address.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Password field is required.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password_ChangeEmail { get; set; }
}

public class ChangePasswordModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The OldPassword field is required.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string OldPassword { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The New Password field is required.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [CustomPassword(8, 15, ErrorMessage = "The password is invalid.")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Confirm Password field is required.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The passwords do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

2) Create a combined model

```
public class InputModel
{
    public LoginModel LoginModel { get; set; }
    public ChangePasswordModel ChangePasswordModel { get; set; }

}
```

3) add two post actions

```
    public IActionResult LoginPost(InputModel model)
    {
        ...
        return View("InputPage", model);
    } 
    public IActionResult ChangePasswordPost(InputModel model)
    {
        ...
        return View("InputPage", model);
    }
```

4) use the combined model in your cshtml page

```
@model InputModel
...
@using (Html.BeginForm("LoginPost", "Home")) {
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LoginModel.Email)
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />

}
```

Comment: I have one concern on this, if I have to explain why we have taken 2 different model and putting inside 3rd model, how would I do that? If possible please give me any idea.

Comment: MVC supports binding not only flat models, but also complex models and collections. And this particular case uses the behavior of validation, in which only those parts of model are validated that are instantiated. When Login form is posted back, then ChangePassword model is not instantiated and is not validated.